# What is the max value of the rotate parameter of a logrotate configuration file?

Tags: logrotate

I would just like to make sure I can put in a relatively large value like 730 for two years without having something unexpected happen.

Comment: The only limit I can imagine would be the number of files that can be in a directory (thousands), and the disk space available. I don't see why `logrotate` itself would impose an arbitrary limit and not mention it in the manual.

Comment: to keep one year of many log file, i had to put 18888 as the number of this rotate directive, i will tell you the result next months